# PHP unserialization of 2D array element does not work as expected

Tags: php, serialization, multidimensional-array

I know there were some similar questions here, but none of them seems to me be exactly what my problem is about or understanding them required more advanced knowledge than I have.

What I try to do:

- store $_POST values in an array
- serialize that array
- store the array in 2D $_SESSION that consist three similar arrays
- retrieve the data from the $_SESSION array directly on the other page

My attempt is described below

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === 'POST') {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];

    $assocArray = ['name' => $_POST['name'], 'surname' => $surname, 'age' => $age];

    $assocArraySerialized = serialize($assocArray);

    $_SESSION += ['etap1' => $assocArraySerialized];

    echo unserialize($_SESSION['etap1']['name']);
}
```

When I try to echo the item I receive:

- Warning: Illegal string offset 'name'
- unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes in *specific localhost path...*

I checked whether the $_POST works and when I echo $_POST['name'] I can see the desired value. When I var_dump the $_SESSION i can see that it got serialized correctly.

How can I have the same restoring data from $_SESSION?

Comment: You store a string in $_SESSION["etap1"], but in unserialize() you try to access an array which it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Natha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this   `echo unserialize($_SESSION['etap1']['name']);` try

```
$var = unserialize($_SESSION['etap1']);
echo $var['name'];
```

Comment: That's correct. I were storing the array in $_SESSION in the wrong way in the first place. That solves my problem. Thank you!